# Enable if to check whether the passed type is a compliant function?

Tags: templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, type-traits, enable-if

Consider the following code:

```
template <class Function, class = typename std::enable_if</*SOMETHING*/>::type>
apply(Function&& f);
```

which execute the provided function.

To use SFINAE, I would like to check whether the function satisfy the following conditions:

- it takes one parameter convertible to `const unsigned int`
- it returns something convertible to a `std::string`

What do I have to write instead of `/*SOMETHING*/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified a return value for `apply`, I'll choose `int`:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <class Function,
  class = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<
      decltype(std::declval<Function>()(std::declval<const unsigned int>())),std::string>::value>::type>
int apply(Function&& f);
```

Breaking it down: this ensures that a `Function`:

```
std::declval<Function>()
```

called with a `const unsigned int` parameter:

```
std::declval<Function()(std::declval<const unsigned int>())
```

has a return type:

```
decltype(std::declval<Function()(std::declval<const unsigned int>()))
```

that is convertible to `std::string`:

```
std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<Function()(std::declval<const unsigned int>())), std::string>
```

whew.